# Global variable in JS reset after JSON call

Tags: javascript, html, json

FIRST TIM POSTIN HERE>>PLZ ADVISE IF QUESTION OR FORMAT UNCLEAR

The following code retrieves a list of routes and associated co-ordinates. The list is presented as a clickable table.

```js
$("#listAll").click(function() {
  $.mobile.navigate("#page31");
  if (routes.length == 0) {
    mLoader('show');
    $.getJSON("tbs.ashx" + "?callback=?" + "&method=getAllRoutes", {
      format: "json"
    }).always(
      function(result) {
        routes = result.routes;
        var tbl = '<table width="100%" data-role="table" id="table-column-toggle" data-mode="columntoggle" class="table-stroke table-stripe"><thead><tr class="ui-bar-b"><th>No.</th><th>From</th><th>To</th></tr></thead>';
        tbl += '<tbody>';
        for (j = 0; j < routes.length; j++) {
          var fr = inArray(stops, routes[j].fr);
          var to = inArray(stops, routes[j].to);
          tbl += '<tr onclick="ListSchedule1(' + routes[j].id + ');mapRoute33(' + routes[j].id + ',' + routes[j].fr + ',' + routes[j].to + ')" style="cursor: pointer;"><td>' + routes[j].name + '</td><td>' + fr.name + '</td><td>' + to.name + '</td></tr>';
        }
        tbl += '</tbody></table>';
        $("#routes31").html(tbl);
        mLoader('hide');
      }

    );
  }
});
```

**The function mapRoute33 is passse the variable  routes[j].id.

I am now trying to store this value to pass to a new HTML page. This value keeps gettng reset.**

Upon clicking a route in the list, the map for the route is drawn in a new HTML #page31.

Now, in #page31; upon click "info" button brings up a table in page #321 with the schedule for that route.

In order to retrieve the data, the value of routes[j].id is needed however the assignment in the js below is keeps resetting.

```
    v_route_id = route_id;  //where v_route_id has been declared as a global variable.
```

```js
  mapRoute33 = function(routeid, startid, stopid) {

    //global variable assignment

    v_route_id = routeid;

    $("#map33").height($(window).height() - 40);

    $("#map33").html();

    $.mobile.navigate("#page33");

    if (map33 == null) {

      setTimeout(function() {

          var myOptions = {

            styles: [{
              "featureType": "landscape",
              "stylers": [{
                "hue": "#FFBB00"
              }, {
                "saturation": 43.400000000000006
              }, {
                "lightness": 37.599999999999994
              }, {
                "gamma": 1
              }]
            }, {
              "featureType": "road.highway",
              "stylers": [{
                "hue": "#FFC200"
              }, {
                "saturation": -61.8
              }, {
                "lightness": 45.599999999999994
              }, {
                "gamma": 1
              }]
            }, {
              "featureType": "road.arterial",
              "stylers": [{
                "hue": "#FF0300"
              }, {
                "saturation": -100
              }, {
                "lightness": 51.19999999999999
              }, {
                "gamma": 1
              }]
            }, {
              "featureType": "road.local",
              "stylers": [{
                "hue": "#FF0300"
              }, {
                "saturation": -100
              }, {
                "lightness": 52
              }, {
                "gamma": 1
              }]
            }, {
              "featureType": "water",
              "stylers": [{
                "hue": "#0078FF"
              }, {
                "saturation": -13.200000000000003
              }, {
                "lightness": 2.4000000000000057
              }, {
                "gamma": 1
              }]
            }, {
              "featureType": "poi",
              "stylers": [{
                "hue": "#00FF6A"
              }, {
                "saturation": -1.0989010989011234
              }, {
                "lightness": 11.200000000000017
              }, {
                "gamma": 1
              }]
            }],

            zoom: 10,

            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-20.2838936, 57.5284781),

            mapTypeControl: false,

            scaleControl: false,

            streetViewControl: false,

            rotateControl: false,

            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

          };

          map33 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map33"), myOptions);

          croute = inArray(routes, routeid);

          polyArr33 = [];

          var pts = [];

          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

          var vertices = croute.pts;

          var verticesArray = vertices.split("|");

          for (k = 0; k < verticesArray.length; k++) {

            var ll = verticesArray[k].split(",");

            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(ll[1], ll[0]);

            pts.push(point);

            bounds.extend(point);

          }

          var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({

            path: pts,

            strokeColor: "red",

            strokeOpacity: 0.6,

            strokeWeight: 5

          });

          polyArr33.push(poly);

          poly.setMap(map33);

          map33.fitBounds(bounds);



          for (w = 0; w < croute.stops.length; w++) {

            var gr = {

              path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,

              scale: 5,

              strokeColor: 'red',

              strokeWeight: 4

            };

            var fp = new MarkerWithLabel({

              position: new google.maps.LatLng(croute.stops[w].lat, croute.stops[w].lng),

              draggable: false,

              icon: gr,

              labelContent: croute.stops[w].name,

              labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(-12, 18),

              labelClass: 'stp',

              labelStyle: {

                opacity: 0.8

              }

            });

            fp.setMap(map33);

            polyArr33.push(fp);



          }



          var start = inArray(stops, startid);

          var gr = {

            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,

            scale: 5,

            strokeColor: 'black',

            strokeWeight: 4

          };

          var fp = new MarkerWithLabel({

            position: new google.maps.LatLng(start.lat, start.lng),

            draggable: false,

            icon: gr,

            labelContent: start.stop,

            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(-12, 18),

            labelClass: 'trm',

            labelStyle: {

              opacity: 0.8

            }

          });

          fp.setMap(map33);

          polyArr33.push(fp);



          var stop = inArray(stops, stopid);

          var gr = {

            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,

            scale: 5,

            strokeColor: 'black',

            strokeWeight: 4

          };

          var fp = new MarkerWithLabel({

            position: new google.maps.LatLng(stop.lat, stop.lng),

            draggable: false,

            icon: gr,

            labelContent: stop.stop,

            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(-12, 18),

            labelClass: 'trm',

            labelStyle: {

              opacity: 0.8

            }

          });

          fp.setMap(map33);

          polyArr33.push(fp);




          if (navigator.geolocation) {

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {

              var gr = {

                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,

                scale: 2,

                strokeColor: 'red',

                strokeWeight: 4

              };

              var fp = new MarkerWithLabel({

                position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),

                draggable: false,

                icon: gr,

                labelContent: "YOU",

                labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(-12, 18),

                labelClass: 'stp',

                labelStyle: {

                  opacity: 0.8

                }

              });

              fp.setMap(map33);

              polyArr33.push(fp);

            });

          }




        },

        200);

    } else {

      setTimeout(function() {

          for (var i = 0; i < polyArr33.length; i++) {

            polyArr33[i].setMap(null);

          }

          polyArr33 = [];

          croute = inArray(routes, routeid);

          var pts = [];

          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

          var vertices = croute.pts;

          var verticesArray = vertices.split("|");

          for (k = 0; k < verticesArray.length; k++) {

            var ll = verticesArray[k].split(",");

            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(ll[1], ll[0]);

            pts.push(point);

            bounds.extend(point);

          }

          var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({

            path: pts,

            strokeColor: "red",

            strokeOpacity: 0.6,

            strokeWeight: 5

          });

          polyArr33.push(poly);

          poly.setMap(map33);

          map33.fitBounds(bounds);



          for (w = 0; w < croute.stops.length; w++) {

            var gr = {

              path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,

              scale: 5,

              strokeColor: 'red',

              strokeWeight: 4

            };

            var fp = new MarkerWithLabel({

              position: new google.maps.LatLng(croute.stops[w].lat, croute.stops[w].lng),

              draggable: false,

              icon: gr,

              labelContent: croute.stops[w].name,

              labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(-12, 18),

              labelClass: 'stp',

              labelStyle: {

                opacity: 0.8

              }

            });

            fp.setMap(map33);

            polyArr33.push(fp);



          }



          var start = inArray(stops, startid);

          var gr = {

            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,

            scale: 5,

            strokeColor: 'black',

            strokeWeight: 4

          };

          var fp = new MarkerWithLabel({

            position: new google.maps.LatLng(start.lat, start.lng),

            draggable: false,

            icon: gr,

            labelContent: start.stop,

            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(-12, 18),

            labelClass: 'trm',

            labelStyle: {

              opacity: 0.8

            }

          });

          fp.setMap(map33);

          polyArr33.push(fp);



          var stop = inArray(stops, stopid);

          var gr = {

            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,

            scale: 5,

            strokeColor: 'black',

            strokeWeight: 4

          };

          var fp = new MarkerWithLabel({

            position: new google.maps.LatLng(stop.lat, stop.lng),

            draggable: false,

            icon: gr,

            labelContent: stop.stop,

            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(-12, 18),

            labelClass: 'trm',

            labelStyle: {

              opacity: 0.8

            }

          });

          fp.setMap(map33);

          polyArr33.push(fp);



          if (navigator.geolocation) {

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {

              var gr = {

                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,

                scale: 2,

                strokeColor: 'red',

                strokeWeight: 4

              };

              var fp = new MarkerWithLabel({

                position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),

                draggable: false,

                icon: gr,

                labelContent: "YOU",

                labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(-12, 18),

                labelClass: 'stp',

                labelStyle: {

                  opacity: 0.8

                }

              });

              fp.setMap(map33);

              polyArr33.push(fp);

            });

          }

        },

        200);

    }



  };
```

Plz help in passing this value to a new HTML page #page321.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make an array for route ids and save all the route id's in that array. In that way it won't be reset and you can easily pass it to another page.

Comment: I would like to retrieve the routeid for the route clicked from the list/table to use in another page

Comment: storing to an array will keep the list of all route_id

Comment: yes at one time you can do both things save it in an array and the function too.

Comment: the table lists multiple routes each having a specific routeid. upon clicking a route n the list, the speciic routeid is passed to the JS function.  now this routeid is used to build the map and display it in a new HTML page. From this page i would like to bring u a schedule for the specific route.  Now seting a global variable n JS function map33 above deos not work. the vriable keeps resetting

Comment: It is resetting because you are creating one variable for all the route id's either create a array or write multiple variable.

Comment: ahmed thnx for ur reply......there issomething i am missing surely. The onclick event  for the table passes only one roueid to the funcion map33. so what is it u mean by using array? Kindly advise?

Comment: Now finally understand stand your problem. Instead of making it global. Save that specific route id in local storage and call it on your new html page. this is way it only reset when you a user click a new route.

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/ahmedkhan92/qf6gdc6q/1/ and get it on your new page.

Comment: I have also done the same technique in one of my routing code.